# how to show dynamic chart based on user selection

Tags: birt

i am very new to Birt Tool,

I created one Bar chart, here my doubt is, can we change type of chart dynamically based user selection,

i.e

for example  End user select pie chart option from jsp list, based on the user selection i want to change chart dyamically dynamically

please guide me

Advanced Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but not quite as you describe.  Each chart type has subtly different characteristics making switching the type at run time problematic.  The way I have solved this is to add each of the chart types you want to support to your report.  Then set the visibility property fore each control (chart) to "false" so they are hidden on load.  You can then use some scripting on the report to dynamically show a report based on a user's selection.

This post from the BIRT Exchange will give you the client-side script you need:  http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1412-showhide-chart-with-radio-button/

Good Luck!